# Aerospike: count all objects in a namespace?

Tags: aerospike

So I've been going through Aerospike's documentations, and I still fail to understand how to get the number of master (not-replicated) records in a names-space via the Java API (not AQL).. any help?

Comment: You can make info protocol calls from the client's API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this with a server running on localhost, port 3000. You can explore the Info class further and use better constructs. I have 10,000 objects in a namespace called 'test'.

```
String output = Info.request("127.0.0.1", 3000, "namespace/test");
String[] mp = output.split(";") ; 
console.printf(mp[0]);
```

I got the following output on my console:

```
objects=10000
```

Comment: The number of objects doesn't match what I have on the cluster.. :/
form Info I get the following stats:

type=memory
objects=1118883051
sub-objects=0
master-objects=547722220
master-sub-objects=0
prole-objects=571160831
prole-sub-objects=0
expired-objects=430023864
repl-factor=2
default-ttl=0
max-ttl=315360000
...

But according to AMC I have 2,902,384,187 Master objects

Comment: master-objects is what you are looking for? parse accordingly. proles are the replicas on that node.  just wanted to share with you the API pathway to what you are trying to retrieve.

Answer (score 2):

I repeated with a three node cluster. 10,000 master objects, replication factor of 2.  Created cluster by running 3 aerospike processes on same VM but separated ports as 3000, 4000 & 5000.

Java code (not parsing the string):

```
console.printf("\nNode at Port 3000\n");
console.printf(Info.request("127.0.0.1", 3000, "namespace/test"));  

console.printf("\nNode at Port 4000\n");
console.printf(Info.request("127.0.0.1", 4000, "namespace/test"));

console.printf("\nNode at Port 5000\n");
console.printf(Info.request("127.0.0.1", 5000, "namespace/test"));
```

Relevant Output:

```
Node at Port 3000
objects=6537;sub_objects=0;master_objects=3286;master_sub_objects=0;prole_objects=3251;prole_sub_objects=0;...
Node at Port 4000
objects=6674;sub_objects=0;master_objects=3294;master_sub_objects=0;prole_objects=3380;prole_sub_objects=0;...
Node at Port 5000
objects=6789;sub_objects=0;master_objects=3420;master_sub_objects=0;prole_objects=3369;prole_sub_objects=0;...
```

Cross check with asadm

```
asadm>info
```

3-node cluster, relevant output:
[image]

Comment: OK, I see the issue - the output is the number of objects per node. As I'm using a c-name for the cluster, I don't have access to each node separately. What can I do?

Comment: Got that worked out -> `client.getNodes.foreach(node => node.getHost.name)`